# How to create a 3 column responsive design with column 1 as optional and column 3 with minimum width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I want to create an HTML layout like http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/blog-promotion/best-twitter-practices-for-improving-visibility/ where the left most column is shown only on higher screen sizes, and the right most column has a fixed width of 345px.

With bootstrap 3, I have tried the following.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">  
        <!--left-->
        <div class="col-sm-3">  
        </div>
        <!--/left-->

        <!--center-->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        </div>
        <!--/center-->

        <!--right-->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        </div>
        <!--/right-->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

But it is creating stacked columns. Any help will be great.

Comment: You need class prefixes for other media querys. Learn more in http://getbootstrap.com/css/ Grid options section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until we get widespread CSS flexbox support, I like display: table-cell for fluid horizontal layouts. Take a look at this quick sample: http://jsfiddle.net/zn6z3/ You would use media queries to hide the left column at a certain width, and the middle column would just expand to fill the space that was lost.

The great thing about table-cell is that you can define fixed widths on some columns and no explicit widths on the others. Columns without widths defined will expand to fill the space of the table. This is a huge advantage over float-based layouts.

Here's my sample HTML & CSS

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="col" id="left">Content</div>
    <div class="col" id="middle">Content</div>
    <div class="col" id="right">Content</div>
</div>


* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
    #page .col {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    #left {
        width: 150px;
        background: #777
    }
    #middle {
        width: auto;
        background: #aaa;
    }
    #right {
        width: 345px;
        background: #ccc;
    }
```

Comment: Note that I use box-sizing: border-box to reset the box model for these elements so that the padding I've added is included as part of the width calculation.

Comment: Well if you want a custom layout that you cant accomplish with Bootstrap, then it's time to chuck Bootstrap. I only have a vague familiarity with what Bootstrap does.

Comment: @NickAngiolillo : thanks for the answer. Thats almost close to what I was looking for. But few concerns.

1) Its not bootstrap
2) On lower resolutions, the right column should be under the middle one.

Comment: @Mic Sorry, I don't know Bootstrap. This is just a general approach I would take, which you could still use with Bootstrap as a customization. For a stacked right column at low resolutions, you would use a media to set the columns to display: block so they stack.

Comment: @NickAngiolillo : thanks for this. It was helpful. Accepted. I used this for the main layout and bootstrap for the rest.

Comment: @Mic Great. I think that's a solid plan.